# Custom Loop Pagination in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

im using this custom loop within a wordpress page. It works great (although it has been simplified here). However, it displays 100's of search results on one page. Because it is a custom loop, i am struggling to get it to work with some pagination (ideally 10 per page). Has anyone achieved this before and willing to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks ...

```
    <ul id="property-holder">
    <?php if ( $location_query->have_posts() ) :
    $row_counter = 0;

    while ( $location_query->have_posts() ) :
    $location_query->the_post();

    $date = get_field("availdate");
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

    if ($date > $future) {
    $row_counter += 1;

    echo '<li id="property-item">';
    echo '<p>' . 'Test' . '</p>';
    echo '</li>';

    } 

    endwhile;

    else :

    echo 'No Results';
    endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </ul>

    <nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous 10 Results') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Next 10 Results &raquo;') ?>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is actually a page or the deafault search.php. if this is the default search, why are you running a custom query. Use `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you've definded `$location_query` like this `$location_query = new WP_Query($args);`, now in your args add `posts_per_page => 10`. This will split your results in 10 items per page. If your pagination doesn't show new items on the next page make your query like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your post type',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$location_query = new WP_Query($args);
```